# MVC Razor Call JS function in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to call the JS function like this:  `defaultDate = "test();"` in my  `@Html.ActionLink`. JS function never called...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Create", new { calendarId = Model.CalendarId, year = Model.Year , defaultDate = "test();" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `onclick="test()` in the html attributes - but its the 21st century, so use use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Create", new { calendarId = Model.CalendarId, year = Model.Year, defaultDate = string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", DateTime.Now) }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming web code, you need to understand at which points various code blocks are run.

Think of it as two major steps:

**Step 1:** The server generates all of the html, css and javascript and send it to the client. In ASP.NET-MVC, you code this through razor files and controller methods.

**Step 2:** The browser (or client) renders the html and runs any javascript.

In your case, you are trying to generate a date and pass it as the `defaultDate` parameter to a server method. This is all part of step 1. Step 1 is performed independently of any browser. For this reason, you cannot run any javascript at this point.